# What should be the value of Index in Sample Texture2dArray in Unity Shader Graph?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I have a Texture2dArray, and I want to sample a specific Texture2D from it provided an index. Let's say there are `n` textures in the array. How would I get the `i`-th of them?

I tried 0-indexing with integer (`i`-th texture has index `i`) and indexing as float value from 0 to 1, but neither worked.

Here's my shader graph:

[image: Image: Shader Graph screenshot]

Comment: What does `neither worked` mean exactly? Any errors? Are all your texture exactly equal in dimensions? Note from [`Texture2DArray`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2DArray.html) "... which is an array of **same size & format** textures ..."

Comment: @derHugo It means that it was always displaying only the first two textures in the array, and never the third (I have currently 3 textures in the array).